# Change the names of multiple cells in R using a function

Tags: r, function, mapping

Consider the following data frame:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(1:5,rep(1,5)), c("id", "value"))
```

I want to change the names for multiple cells in the column "id". Let's say I want to change the following:

```
df$id[df$id %In% 2:3] <- 1
df$id[df$id == 4]     <- 3
```

However, instead of using the code above, I want to create a function, where I can do the transformation more "smooth" (because I have a lot of data frames, where I need to change the names for the cells). I want to create a function:

```
mapping <- function(...) {
  ...
}
```

where I afterward can create a simple and smooth mapping function for my `df`, where I only have to specific the "old" and the "new" names for the cells. Something like this:

```
df_mapping <- function(...) {
  2.1
  3.1
  4.3  
}
```

And then I can apply the function on my data and specific which column it should do it for, and it will work in the same way as the code with `gsub`:

```
df <- df_mapping(df,id)
```

Is it possible to create that mapping function?

Comment: You are right. I have changed the question. However, in my case I have a lot of names that needed to be changed. So I still need a function, where I easily can define which cells that should be changed.

Comment: would the below function helps in changing

Comment: Do you have the replacer values different ? i.e. suppose you want to replace 2 with 1 and 4 with 5?

Comment: Hm. I have a lot of cells that needed to be changed. For instance, some values should be x, and some others should be y, and so on (for instance, consider that also all 4's should be changed to 3). So it will be more convenient if I could have something like the df_mapping function, where I specify which cells that should change and thereafter I can apply it on my df. I have changed the quesion.

Comment: I have a couple of options posted below.  The one you mentioined now should work as well

Comment: Perfect. Only one thing: Is it possible to change the function, so I can specify it like this f2(df, "id", c(2, 5), c(3, 6)) instead, and get the same result? And thanks very much for your help :-)

Comment: Yes, that is updated in that function `f2`

Comment: In the current version, whereever, there is 2, it is replaced with 3 and those with 5 and replaced with 6 i.e. the replaced column will be `1 3 3 4 6`

Comment: Hm. When I use the code, 2 is replaced with 5, and 3 is replaced with 6.

Comment: I am not getting that output.  Can you check the `df` again.  Is it the original 'df' used

Comment: Yes, I am sure I am using the original 'df'. Have you updated the code for f2? f3 works fine :-)

Comment: But otherwise, f3 works for me. So thank you very very much for your help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we need a function, then can have a 'data' argument, column name, values to replace and replacer value, then create the logical condition, subset the column, assign with replacer_val and return the dataset after the assignment

```
f1 <- function(dat, colnm, values_to_replace, replacer_val) {
           dat[[colnm]][dat[[colnm]] %in% values_to_replace] <- replacer_val
         return(dat)
    }

f1(df, "id", c(2, 3), 1)
```

-output

```
#   id value
#1  1     1
#2  1     1
#3  1     1
#4  4     1
#5  5     1
```

---

To replace values with corresponding sets of replacers,

```
f2 <- function(dat, colnm, values_to_replace, replacer_vals) {

          nm1 <- setNames(replacer_vals, values_to_replace)
          v1 <- nm1[as.character(dat[[colnm]])]
          i1 <- !is.na(v1)
          dat[[colnm]][i1] <- v1[i1]
        return(dat)
 

    }
     


f2(df, "id", c(2, 3), c(5, 6))
#  id value
#1  1     1
#2  5     1
#3  6     1
#4  4     1
#5  5     1
```

---

Or another option is to create a key/value dataset and use `merge` or `join`

```
library(data.table)
f3 <- function(dat, colnm, values_to_replace, replacer_vals) {
        keydat <- data.frame(key = values_to_replace, val = replacer_vals)
       names(keydat)[1] <- colnm
       dt <- as.data.table(dat)
      dt[keydat, (colnm) := val, on = colnm][]
      return(dt)
 }

f3(df, "id", c(2, 5), c(3, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a `mapping` like below could help

```
mapping <- function(df, id, to_replace, obj_value) {
  transform(df, id = replace(id, id %in% to_replace, obj_value))
}
```

e.g.,

```
> mapping(df, id, c(2, 3), 1)
  id value
1  1     1
2  1     1
3  1     1
4  4     1
5  5     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`'s `recode` function

```
mapping <- function(data, col, old, new) {
  data[[col]] <- dplyr::recode(data[[col]], !!!setNames(new, old))
  data
}

mapping(df, "id", c(2, 3), c(7L, 8L))

#  id value
#1  1     1
#2  7     1
#3  8     1
#4  4     1
#5  5     1
```